# How to complete Vakil's proof that the composition of projective morphisms are projective when the target is quasicompact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-schemes

For this question, a morphism $\pi : X \rightarrow Y$ is projective iff there exists a finite type quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on $Y$ such that $X$ is isomorphic (as a $Y-$scheme) to a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$. I am interested in finding a way to solve this problem as it is presented in Vakil, and not in solving it using completly different methods (such as can be found in e.g. EGA II $5.5.5$, or Stacks Tag $01W7$, although under the additional assumptions that $Y$ is either quasi-separated or Noetherian).

In exercise 17.3.B of Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" notes, he asks to show that if $\pi : X\rightarrow Y$ and $\rho : Y \rightarrow Z$ are projective morphisms and $Z$ is quasi-compact, then $\rho \circ \pi$ is also projective. The hint he gives is to show that in the case where $Z$ is affine, if $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}$ are the very ample line bundles on $X,Y$ coming from pulling back the respective $\mathcal{O}(1)$ bundles from the projective bundles $X$ and $Y$ are closed subschemes of, then there is some $m$ such that $\mathcal{L}\otimes \pi^*(\mathcal{M})^{\otimes m}$ is $\rho\circ \pi-$very ample. He then suggests using that $Z$ is quasicompact to cover it by finitely many open affine pieces, but I can't work out how to use this to prove the result. My first instinct would be to glue together the morphisms constructed over each affine piece, or to extend the construction globally, but in this case neither approach works.

I can see that covering $Z$ by finitely many affine pieces $U_i$ allows us to find a fixed $m$ such that $\mathcal{L}\otimes \pi^*(\mathcal{M})^{\otimes m}$ is $\rho \circ \pi-$relatively very ample upon restriction to each $(\rho \circ \pi)^{-1}(U_i)$, but I don't understand how to use this to show that it is globally $\rho \circ \pi-$relatively very ample. Vakil does mention several times (and later proves) that with locally Noetherian hypotheses, the property of a line bundle on the source being relatively very ample can be checked affine-locally on the target, which would finish the proof if $Z$ was Noetherian, but this isn't part of the hypothesis of $17.3.B$.

My question then, is this:

> Is it possible to finish this approach to the exercise, perhaps by showing that $\mathcal{L}\otimes \pi^*(\mathcal{M})^{\otimes m}$ is $\rho \circ \pi-$relatively very ample globally given that it is locally? Or is it really the case that you need to either assume that $Z$ is Noetherian, or take a completely different approach to the proof (such as characterising projective morphisms to quasicompact schemes as those that or both quasiprojective and proper)?

Comment: Note that Stacks and EGA II do assume furthermore that the base is quasi-separated or noetherian (as topological space), respectively. Also, this MO question by Vakil himself is related.

Comment: @Ben Ah, I didn't realise that "Schemes" in EGA didn't really mean schemes, but rather (quasi?)-separated schemes. I did think it was odd that stacks had a weaker statement than EGA... Also, I know the question you're referring to (I don't think the link worked) but there weren't any useful answers and Vakil didn't explain his approach (although no-one contradicted it, either).

Comment: This http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105172/must-the-composition-of-projective-morphisms-be-projective is the MO question referred to.  I think Vakil is claiming a stronger result than exists elsewhere in the literature, but since no proof is given, I wouldn't automatically assume it is correct unless you can actually prove it yourself.

Comment: I think it is possible to imitate the proof of Stacks' [tag 01VR](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VR), implication $(2) \Rightarrow (4)$. Note that Vakil has an extra assumption: that the sheaf be not just generated in degree one, but also of finite type; this requires a bit more extra care, maybe.

Comment: @Ben this additionally assumes that the composition is a quasi-compact morphism, which would imply that $X$ would be quasi-compact as $Z$, so is not quite applicable to this case, I think (since you'd need qcqs for the pushforward of $\mathcal{L}$ to be quasicoherent). Aside from all that, it's not clear to me how various morphisms of sheaves correspond to morphisms of projectivisations. I know that morphisms of sheaves of graded algebras (with some restrictions) induce morphisms of relative proj and so for projectivsations of finite type sheaves it's enough to give maps of the sheaves ...

Comment: and that surjections give closed embeddings, but I'm not sure how morphisms of projectivisations give rise to morphisms of sheaves (since, e.g., not all morphisms of proj of graded algebras arise as morphisms of the underlying algebras). It's quite possibly something not that hard to think through, though (having said this, it might be something to do with the qcqs assumption).

Comment: But isn't a projective morphism in Vakil's definition quasi-compact and proper?

Comment: @Ben Oh yeah, of course they're quasi-compact, since locally it's just projection to $A$ of $\operatorname{Proj}$ of some finitely generated graded $A-$algebra.

Comment: @TomOldfield Since [proper morphisms are quasi-compact](http://mathoverflow.net/a/23528), you can use \[Stacks, [Tag 01VR](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VR)\] to show that relative very amplitude is local on target. Alternatively, you can use [EGAII, 4.4.10(ii)], which says $\mathscr{L} \otimes \rho^*(\mathscr{M}^{\otimes m})$ is $(\rho \circ \pi)$-very ample for all $m \gg 0$. But this result ends up using the local criterion in [EGAII, 4.4.5], which is the analogue of the Stacks result above.

Comment: @TomOldfield I guess one thing to mention, though, is that the definition of relative very amplitude in Vakil is slightly different from that in EGA or Stacks. I think \[Stacks, [0C6J](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C6J)\] is what makes these definitions the same.

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Yes, Ben already linked to 01VR, but also pointed out that we'd know to show that the pushforward of the candidate sheaf for being very ample is finite type (which may or may not be hard). Also, I don't really understand the equivalences between maps of projective spaces and maps of graded algebras being used, as I mentioned in an earlier comment. I'll try and think about it at some point if I get a chance, but if you think you could post an explanation, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Dear @TakumiMurayama, the major difference in the definitions is that Vakil wants the degree one part to be a module of finite type; can we make sure that the push-forward of an invertible module along a proper morphism (or a composition of projective morphisms) is locally finitely generated if the base is assumed to be quasi-compact only and not locally noetherian?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit.** I decided to just rewrite a proof. I still need quasi-separatedness, however.

**Theorem** [Stacks, Tag [0C4P](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C4P)]**.** *Suppose $\pi\colon X \to Y$ and $\rho\colon Y \to Z$ are projective morphisms, and $Z$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated. Then, $\pi \circ \rho$ is projective.*

*Proof.* Let $\mathscr{M}$ be the $\rho$-very ample line bundle on $Y$. Let $X \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Y(\mathscr{E})$ be the closed embedding factoring $\pi$, where $\mathscr{E}$ is a finite type quasicoherent sheaf on $Y$. Now we claim the following:

**Key Claim.** *There exists a finite type quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ on $Z$ and a surjection*
$$\rho^*\mathscr{G} \twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}$$
*for $m \gg 0$.*

We postpone the proof of the Key Claim for now. Using this surjection, we have a sequence of morphisms
$$X \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Y(\mathscr{E}) \cong \mathbf{P}_Y(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}) \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Y(\rho^*\mathscr{G})$$
whose composition is still a closed embedding. Moreover, we have an isomorphism 
$$\mathbf{P}_Y(\rho^*\mathscr{G}) \cong \mathbf{P}_Z(\mathscr{G}) \times_Z Y$$
by [EGAII, 4.1.3.1].

Next, let $Y \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Z(\mathscr{F})$ be the closed embedding factoring $\rho$, where $\mathscr{F}$ is a finite type quasicoherent sheaf on $Z$. Then, we have a closed embedding
$$X \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Z(\mathscr{G}) \times_Z Y \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Z(\mathscr{G}) \times_Z \mathbf{P}_Z(\mathscr{F})$$
and composing by the (relative) Segre embedding [EGAII, §4.3], we get a closed embedding
$$X \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}_Z(\mathscr{G} \otimes \mathscr{F})$$
Since $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{F}$ were finite type quasi-coherent sheaves on $Z$, we have that $\pi \circ \rho$ is indeed projective. $\blacksquare$

We now return to the proof of the Key Claim. This is where we use that $Z$ is quasi-separated.

*Proof of Key Claim.* Since projective morphisms are proper, we can apply [Vakil, 17.3.9] to say that $\mathscr{M}$ is in fact $\rho$-ample, and so for $m \gg 0$, we have that $\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}$ is $\rho$-globally generated, that is, we have that the canonical map
$$\rho^*\rho_*\!\left(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}\right) \twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}$$
is a surjection. By [Görtz–Wedhorn, 10.50] we can write
$$\rho_*\!\left(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}\right) = \varinjlim \mathscr{G}_\lambda$$
for the filtered system of finite type quasi-coherent subsheaves $\mathscr{G}_\lambda \subset \rho_*\!\left(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}\right)$. Since $\rho^*$ is the left adjoint of $\rho_*$, it preserves colimits, and the surjection above becomes a surjection
$$\varinjlim \rho^*\mathscr{G}_\lambda \twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}$$
and by [Görtz–Wedhorn, 10.47], for $\lambda$ large enough, we have a surjection
$$\rho^*\mathscr{G}_\lambda \twoheadrightarrow \mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}$$
as desired. $\blacksquare$

*Remark.* Here are possible ideas for getting rid of the quasi-separatedness assumption:

1. Try using the affine case. Since $\mathscr{M}$ is ample, we have locally have surjections
   $$\rho^*\mathcal{O}_{U_i}^{\oplus n_i} \twoheadrightarrow \left.\left(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m_i} \right)\right\rvert_{\rho^{-1}(U_i)}$$
   on each element $U_i$ of a finite open affine cover of $Z$. Then, we could hope to glue these surjections together somehow. One method is to extend the sheaves on the left-hand side to finite type quasi-coherent sheaves on all of $Z$, and use [EGAInew, 6.9.10.1], but that still uses quasi-separatedness. The issue is that extension theorems for finite type quasi-coherent sheaves need quasi-separatedness to make their glueing arguments work; see [EGAInew, 6.9; Görtz–Wedhorn, §10.11; Stacks, Tag [01PD](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PD)].
2. In the proof above, to apply [Görtz–Wedhorn, 10.47], all we needed was to write $\rho_*\!\left(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathscr{M}^{\otimes m}\right)$ as a filtered colimit of finite type quasi-coherent sheaves. Perhaps this can be done in this case even without quasi-separatedness.

*Remark.* The Stacks Project [Stacks, Tag [0C4P](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C4P)] also restricts to $Z$ quasi-separated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to address the concerns I raised in the comments. I haven't thought about this too hard since I posted the question, but firstly, I don't know what you mean when you talk about the canonical morphism from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}(\sigma_* \mathscr{K})$. I saw a stack tag about something similar to it earlier but it looked involved and I didn't have time to process it properly. Could you clarify? Secondly, since I'm not sure what this map is, I don't know why it should be a closed embedding. Thirdly I don't know why the factorisation of maps you give holds..

Comment: I also think the relative version of Vakil $8.2.C.$ can probably be taken to be the only if direction of $17.3.A$, namely that if you are a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}(\mathscr{I})$ for some finite type $\mathscr{I}$ (and so by the if direction, a closed subscheme of any $\mathcal{Proj}(\mathscr{I}_{\bullet})$) then you are the projectivisation of some quasicoherent sheaf over the base, finitely generated in degree $1$. But I don't think your final claim follows, all we get is a surjection $\operatorname{Sym}^{\bullet}(\mathcal{G})\rightarrow \mathscr{I}_{\bullet}$ with...

Comment: $\mathcal{Proj}(\mathscr{I}_{\bullet})\cong \mathbb{P}(\sigma_*\mathscr{K})$. I think $\mathscr{I}_{\bullet}$ should locally be the saturation of $\operatorname{Sym}^{\bullet}(\sigma_*(\mathscr{K}))$, but I don't remember the construction off the top of my head. We possibly get a map between these two sheaves of algebras, that's an isomorphism in sufficiently high degree, but that's not enough to show generation in degree $1$.

Comment: Actually, having said all that I realise that for the last part, we're working over an affine base so there's no need to think about relativisations of results about $\operatorname{Proj}$. I think the discrepancy between the two algebras involved still stands though. Although now I think the situation is slightly clearer, we have a surjection from $A_j[X_0,\dots,X_{n-1}]$ to the saturation of $\operatorname{Sym}^{\bullet}\mathscr{K}(X_j)$. I don't see how this would give us the finite generation result we want, but I am typing this out while I think so perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: Ah, in fact I was looking through Vakil again and I notice that exercise $17.3.E.$ asks to show that for $\mathcal{L}$ a finite rank locally free sheaf on $X$, $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ a quasicompact separated morphism with the assumption that $\pi_*\mathcal{L}$ is finite type, there is a canonical morphism $\psi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_(\pi_*(\mathcal{L}))$. He mentions that proving $\pi_*\mathcal{L}$ is finite type is hard work, though feasible with current knowledge. However, this is all in a double starred section after the question at hand, so I would be very surprised if this approach...

Comment: was going to be particularly simple, and I think it can't be the approach he had in mind, unfortunately.

Comment: @TomOldfield just so you have something to think about: I think we can salvage this proof even though we have that saturation issue. The two graded algebras in question are such that they are isomorphic in high degree $d \ge d_0$, and one of them is finitely generated in degree 1. So the degree $d_0$ Veronese subrings of both will be generated in degree 1, hence we know a large power of $\sigma_*\mathscr{K}$ is finitely generated. We can probably just rig our argument at this point so that this is the object we take a projective bundle of at the end...

Comment: @TomOldfield I rewrote the answer. But even after thinking for all this time I think I need $Z$ to be quasi-separated...

Comment: Yes, I think that there is some other assumption needed to make this work.